# dbgrid columns delphi

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I would like to know how to show the column title in dbgrid delphi vertical. At this stage the title headings is a bit long and i want to display them vertical. I am using delphi 2010 and there is nothing in the object inspector to set any allignment settings for vertical or 90 degrees. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At least in Delphi 2009, there's the `Font.Orientation` property which, if you set to 900 (which equals to 90°) will render the font vertically. The problem is how to increase the height of the header or how to re-position the rendered caption, the best would be still to have a owner draw event for this.

Comment: The font.Orientation changes the font to vertical in the dbgrid itself and not the column headings.

Comment: @Pierre: You can set the font for the column header directly. Edit the `Column`, expand the `Title`, expand the `Font`. You can also set it for the entire `DBGrid` using the `TitleFont` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing a couple of things:

- Set the `TDBGrid.TitleFont.Orientation` to `900`, which is 90 degrees.
- Use an interposer class to change the `TDBGrid` first (column header) row height. The interposer class gives you access to the `RowHeights` property of the grid, which isn't published in `TDBGrid`:

```
    implementation

    type
      THackGrid=class(TDBGrid);

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      THackGrid(DBGrid1).RowHeights[0] := 300;        
    end;
```

Calculating the proper height to use for `RowHeights[0]` is an exercise left to you. :-) As @TLama said in his comment, you're better off owner-drawing the grid to get the proper fit and alignment of the text; how to do so would be another question (but there are examples that exist already for doing so, so make sure you look at them first before asking it).